# The method FB.JSON.parse is not officially supported by Facebook and access to it will soon be removed.

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, api

I got this warning message on Chrome whith My facebook application.

The method FB.JSON.parse is not officially supported by Facebook and access to it will soon be removed.

and

The method FB.JSON.stringify is not officially supported by Facebook and access to it will soon be removed.

When this flash is loaded this message appears.
I'm using Facebook Flash AS3 API 1.8.1, SWFObject 2.2.

What does it mean ?

Test here (facebook test): https://apps.facebook.com/vuvuzelagame/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same error on my application.

As you probably know, the [Facebook AS3 API](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/) calls JavaScript functions to communicate with FB, and, as Baris says, this error is a warning that one of those JS functions that it calls is deprecated and will soon be removed.

You can safely ignore it for the present. Hopefully the API will be updated before the function is actually deprecated, otherwise we may get a breaking bug rather than just a warning. I'm going to keep an eye out for updates to the API and upgrade my code as soon as one is released.

Or, if you're feeling really brave, you can go digging in the API source and fix the issue yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

A few days ago, many flash apps suddenly stopped working, if you have this problem follow this steps:

1. If you are using `GraphAPI_Web_1_8_1.swc` delete it
2. Download the modified graph API from here
3. Paste those folders on your library, if you had the facebook folder overwrite it
4. Publish your project

This problem started when facebook changed its file `http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js` in a way that all the calls made from the AS3 file `FacebookJSBridge.as` must be changed from `FB.JSON` to just `JSON`.

([Source](http://ederchrono.com/blog/2012/05/09/fixing-fb-graph-api-for-as3/))

Comment: *Download the modified graph API from here*. From where? is there any update for **GraphAPI_Web_1_8_1.swc**?

Answer (score 0):

FB.JSON.stringify is that a javascript function or actionscript function?

In flash if you are targetting flash player 11 and up you can just use JSON.parse and JSON.stringify, or you can use the JSON class in the com.adobe.serialization package.

If that is a javascript method, just get a json library from the web.

The error just means facebook is no longer supporting/updating that function and they will remove it. It will stop working soon so you should replace your usages of it with something else.